# Gzip compression not enabled

Tags: wordpress, plugin, google

Our wordpress website we need to enable gzip compression
we followed below instruction to enabled.

1. we have wp rocket plugin this plugin automatically added compression mode_deflate lines in .htaccess
2. We try to enable from server side so we followed this below article instruction to enable gzip compression

([https://devops.ionos.com/tutorials/how-to-configure-mod_deflate-for-apache-on-centos-7/#:~:text=The%20mod_deflate%20module%20is%20loaded,.d%2Fmod_deflate.conf%20.&text=Save%20the%20file%20and%20restart%20Apache%20to%20reflect%20changes.](https://devops.ionos.com/tutorials/how-to-configure-mod_deflate-for-apache-on-centos-7/#:%7E:text=The%20mod_deflate%20module%20is%20loaded,.d%2Fmod_deflate.conf%20.&text=Save%20the%20file%20and%20restart%20Apache%20to%20reflect%20changes.))

In this article given edit file `sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_deflate.conf`  and paste the below code

```
<filesMatch "\.(js|html|txt)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</filesMatch>
DeflateCompressionLevel 7
DeflateMemLevel 8
DeflateWindowSize 10
```

we try to do this step we can't save the file when we try to saving file its show 'NO SUCH FILE DIRECTORY'.

and also we tried to edit this file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. This file also can't to save.

Why don't I have a httpd directory.

Comment: Where is your HTTPD installed?  Sometimes /usr/local/apache or /usr/local/apache-version/ or /opt/apache/ - under that you'll find the equivalent conf file. Make sure you validate it `/sbin/service httpd configtest`..